# Checking circle theorems question

Tags: circles

[image]

I was just wondering if these answers were right. I am pretty sure that part a is correct, but part b I am not as confident with.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: As a side note, you didn't have to draw that second angle. The image given in the question works correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks, I completely missed the fact that I didn’t need the second subtended angle and that I could work out the angle straight from the information given.